# WordPress set post thumbnail by plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a plugin which adds images (from the appstore) in articles and it inserts images like `<img src='http://...' />` But is it possible to set such an image on the web as the post thumbnail by code?
Something like "set_post_thumbnail('http://example.com/image.png');"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this if you're comfortable with MySQL. You'll basically run a custom query that manually edits the DB. Check out the docs on the wordpress MySQL global `$wbdp` in the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

It's basically an object that holds the database which you can use to run your own queries.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I know PHP and MySQL so that's not the problem. But I currently don't really know where the information of thumbnails is stored in the database. In the table wp_posts it isn't I think...

Comment: I now found that this is in "wp_postmeta"-table. But there I can only select images located on the server. I think there is now way to do this with MySQL without changing code of the WordPress files..

Comment: Have you checked in wp-posts? Look for post_type: "attachment" or "post-attachment". I'm pretty sure it's one of those.

Comment: I found some with `post_type` 'attachment', post-attachment does not exist. In attachment are all images, which are included in the posts, but there is no special mark for thumbnails or sth.

Comment: That "special mark" is stored as a link in wp_postmeta. You can read more about it here: http://wpbits.wordpress.com/2007/08/08/a-look-inside-the-wordpress-database/

Comment: Oh I found it, thank you very much! But do you know how to make an "_wp_attached_file" which is not located on the same server? (with http://...)?

Comment: You're quite welcome. If I understand your question, you want the option to link to an external image for thumbnails. I've never done this, but it looks like other people have. Check this out: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-external-images-in-post-within-thumbnail

If that doesn't work, I recommend that you mark this question solved and then start a new question that addresses this issue specifically.  You'll get more help that way.